# How do I save a transient object that already exists in an NHibernate session?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, persistence, session-state, castle-activerecord

I have a `Store` that contains a list of `Products`:

```
var store = new Store();
store.Products.Add(new Product{ Id = 1, Name = "Apples" };
store.Products.Add(new Product{ Id = 2, Name = "Oranges" };

Database.Save(store);
```

Now, I want to edit one of the `Products`, but with a transient entity. This will be, for example, data from a web browser:

```
// this is what I get from the web browser, this product should
// edit the one that's already in the database that has the same Id
var product = new Product{ Id = 2, Name = "Mandarin Oranges" };

store.Products.Add(product);
Database.Save(store);
```

However, trying to do it this way gives me an error:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

The reason is because the `store.Products` collection already contains an entity with the same Id. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Have you tried session.Evict(product) before saving the second time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of trying to merge the transient instance. Why not start with the actual instance...simply get the product by id, update the fields, and commit.

```
var product = session.Get<Product>(2);
product.Name = "Mandarin Oranges";
tx.Commit();
```

or the merge way...

```
var product = new Product{ Id = 2, Name = "Mandarin Oranges" };
var mergedProduct = (Product) session.Merge(product);
tx.Commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% positive in this case without more context, but a session merge might work.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/11/08/nhibernate-ndash-cross-session-operations.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, good explanation of why this issue occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You should call Database.SaveOrUpdate(store); instead of pure Save(store) ?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to mention that `Database.Save()` does `NHibernate.ISession.SaveOrUpdate()` behind the scenes.

Comment: SaveOrUpdate won't help in this situation, the error occurs because there is already an object in session.